# Javascript - Best way to implement loading spinner

Tags: javascript, html

New to web-development and trying wrap my head around handling the DOM.
Want to implement a spinner that appears while data is being processed and disappears after.
I figure the order should be something like this

1. on button press, make spinner visible and call data function
2. after data function is finished make spinner invisible again

Using **Bootstrap 5**

Current implementation is something along these lines:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",function(){document.getElementById("spinner").classList.toggle("invisible");})
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",dataProcess());
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",function(){document.getElementById("spinner").classList.toggle("invisible");})
```

I understand the order in which event listeners are added are the order they are executed in but the spinner doesn't toggle at because the DOM doesn't update until all the functions are executed(since it toggled twice by then it's just invisible again). Is there a way to update the DOM between events or a better way to implement the spinner altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",()=>{
    setTimeOut(()=>{
        document.getElementById("spinner").classList.toggle("invisible")
    },600)
    dataProcess();
    document.getElementById("spinner").classList.toggle("invisible")
});
```

Comment: This worked, but putting the data process in setTimeOut gave a better result (made the spinner appear instantly instead of after data process()) in my problem but Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Give a callback function to dataprocess function and make button invisible

Comment: Answers should provide actual code to demonstrate what your suggestion is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).